# Embed javascript in PHP echo

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, variables, echo

```
echo "<td> + manuf + </td>";
```

Is this above ever going to work??

I'm pulling results from a mysql db to edit the contents but need the jQuery functionality to edit it, hence the embedded javascript variable...

EDIT:

Sorry for the lack of context, its related to another question i've asked on here [Mysql edit users orders they have placed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123012/mysql-edit-users-orders-they-have-placed)
this is the end goal. To edit the order i place, i need to pull the results into an environment similar to how the user placed the order. So my thinking was to include the jQuery functionality to add items to a cart etc, then they could press submit and in the same way i used .Ajax to post the data to an insert php script i would post the values to an update php script! Is this backwards thinking, any advice welcomed!

Comment: Your question lacks context. It will work, if you want + manuf + to appear on the page.

Comment: Even in HTML, `<td> + manuf + </td>` won't do anything but write " + manuf + " in a table cell.

Anyway, if you pull result from a database, you shouldn't have to edit it client-side afterwards.

You need to be more specific about the code you use if you want help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at the follwing.

- [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)
- [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)
- [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)

Now your simplest solution under you circumstances is to do go for the [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) method. Let me show you an example:

```
$json_data = array(
    'manuf' => $some_munaf_data
);

echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
   echo "var Data = " . json_encode(json_data);
echo "</script>";
```

This will produce an object called `Data`, and would look like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var Data = {
    munaf : "You value of $some_munaf_data"
}
</script>
```

Then when you need the data just use `Data.munaf` and it will hold the value from the PHP Side.

Answer (score 1):

Would you not echo out the jQuery within a Javascript code island? You need the client-based code (jQuery) to be able to execute after the server-side code (PHP).

```
echo '<td><script language = "JavaScript" type = "text/JavaScript">document.write("");</script></td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is this above ever going to work??

Nope. You'd need to output valid JavaScript for the browser to interpret:

```
echo "<script>document.write('<td>'+manuf+'</td>')</script>";
```

But that is a dreadful construct, and I can't really see why you would need this, seeing as the `td`'s contents are likely to be static at first.

Answer (score 0):

Try just emitting the MySQL content with PHP:

```
echo "<td id='manuf'>".$manuf."</td>"
```

Then get the contents with jQuery like this:

```
var manuf = $('#manuf').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Consume you have the table echoed with php:

```
<table id="sometab">
 <tr>
  <td>
  </td>
 <tr>
</table>
```

The jquery for printing resuls in any td is :nth-child(2) takes 2 table td object :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
   $("#sometab tr td:nth-child(2)").html("bla");
})   
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**i think you cant embed the jquery variable in the php like this .
you just give the class name here from here when edit will be click you will get the variable as in submit click in other questions .**

Answer (score 0):

Is "manuf" a JS variable or part of a PHP output e.g. part of generated ?

Basically this can easily be done by:
mysql thru PHP(*I can't put table tag..sorry.):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
  echo 'tr';
  echo 'td a href="#" class="myres"'.$row->manuf.'/a /td';
  echo '/tr';
}
```

then on your JS just attach a "click" handler

```
$(function() {
   $(".myres").click(function() {
        //my update handler...
   });
});
```

Comment: manuf is a jQuery variable pulled from a table on the same page, so the idea was if i put a js var in php echo, the variable would be filled with actual data once the page appears! if that makes sense?